# I have no cousins in Antarctica. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I have no cousins in Antarctica.
>   I have no skeleton but have exoskeleton.
>   I glow like the moon.
>   I prefer night to day.
>   I can turn my prey into liquid.
>   I can spend in a freezer overnight.
>   I have more eyes but useless.
>   I am venomous.

Hint:

> One of my parts is used as security software.

Who am I?

Comment: Oh, I think I know the answer. Please undo the protection... :(

Comment: @Deusovi Thank you for adding protection to the question..

Comment: Nine different answers and counting (if it wasn't for the protection) - so I guess the eight upvotes should be replaced by flags because the riddle has no unique solution.

Comment: No, it has a unique solution...

Comment: All of the below answers are not true for all the statements in the question..

Comment: "I have no cousins in Antarctica" Is this referring to [Cousins Rock](http://www.geographic.org/geographic_names/antname.php?uni=3223&fid=antgeo_105)? Both Antarctica and the moon are inhabitant. Antarctica is mostly frozen water. Aurora occurs at night in Antarctica.

Comment: No.. Please check the hint..

Comment: Why this question is closed? No one has fully explained all the hints in the question and question is closed as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> possibly still too broad.

Though I think probably

> the first of these two answers (**scorpion**) is the intended one.

---

You could be

> a scorpion.

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> Scorpions can be found on every continent except Antarctica.

I have no skeleton but have exoskeleton.

> Scorpions: Exoskeleton, check.  Skeleton? Negative.

I glow like the moon.

> Many species of scorpions glow when exposed to UV light.

I prefer night to day.

> Scorpions are nocturnal.

I can turn my prey into liquid.

> Scorpions extrude their digestive juices onto their prey, then take it in in liquefied form.

I can spend in a freezer overnight.

> Scorpions can sometimes survive being frozen.

I have more eyes but useless.

> Many scorpions have multiple sets of eyes.  A few species are blind, though most are not.

I am venomous.

> Yep, don't mess with the scorpion.

**Hint**
One of my parts is used as security software.

> Stinger is a McAfee program that targets certain computer viruses.

---

Or you could be

> A toxic glowing millipede of the genus *[Motyxia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motyxia)*
>
>  [image]

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> there are no millipedes of any kind in Antarctica.

I have no skeleton but have exoskeleton.

> The millipede has an exoskeleton.

I glow like the moon.

> This is a bioluminescent genus.

I prefer night to day.

> They are nocturnal.

I can turn my prey into liquid.

> They eat vegetation partially which is broken down by saliva.

I can spend in a freezer overnight.

> but it wouldn't end well.

I have more eyes but useless.

> They are blind.

I am venomous.

> They produce cyanide.

Comment: Correct Answer... Congrats!!! Upvote for you..

Comment: Scorpion is the correct answer.

Answer (score 22):

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> Hurricanes are named like people, but do not go to Antartica.

I have a similarity with moon.

> A full moon can make effects of a hurricane worsen, especially with lunar high tides.

I prefer night than day.

> Jim Sweeney, a meteorologist with National Weather Service in Lake Charles, La., said storms generally strengthen at night because of what he called "latent heat release."  It's at night when the upper and middle part of the atmosphere cools (because the sun is not there to heat it up) and that releases energy in the storms, which turns into winds and moisture.

I like only liquids.

> Hurricanes "grow" by the amount of water they pick up (consume/eat).

I am very strong in fasting.

> A hurricane can remain strong while 'fasting' as they cross over land.

I have useless eyes.

> Hurricanes have eyes that are known for being unusually calm. And as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_(cyclone)) states, "Small/minuscule eyes—those less than 10 nmi (19 km, 12 mi) across—often trigger eyewall replacement cycles, where a new eyewall begins to form outside the original eyewall."

Comment: mage.. you tried well but it is not the answer..

Comment: I'm guessing its not 'storm' either, it would be too similar to 'hurricane'?

Answer (score 11):

It's just a guess but are you a

> Bat

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> No bats in Antarctica

I have a similarity with moon.

I prefer night than day.

> Moon and bats, both are active in night

I like only liquids.

> most bats feed on liquids like blood or nectar

I am very strong in fasting.

> Not sure about that, but probably 2-3 days fasting is good I suppose.

I have useless eyes.

> It is proven that bats have eyes but almost as decorative

Comment: No..bat is not the answer..

Comment: Try you can get the answer..

Comment: Am I close? or some specific answer is seeked here?

Comment: No..The answer is different. And the answer must match all the given statements.

Comment: Not related to the puzzle, but I just wanted to say that most bats eat insects and have very good eyesight.

Answer (score 3):

> Sounds like the Olm (http://io9.gizmodo.com/this-animal-can-go-over-a-decade-without-food-1723304968) - a blind water dwelling salamander (no relatives in antartica), which can go without food for a decade.

Comment: As far as Wiki is concerned, an olm feeds on small crabs, snails and occasionally insects.

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> mosquito

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> They live on every continent except this

I have a similarity with moon.

> **Mo**squit**o** is a 3/4 similarity

I prefer night than day.

> Well, that's true

I like only liquids.

> They drink blood

I am very strong in fasting.

> <strike>Try to catch one and you'll know</strike>"fasting" was not the word I thought of

I have useless eyes.

> Insects have a very specific vision management system

Comment: You mean fasting here, as... ...perhaps a synonym to fast?

Comment: haha.. I'm sorry - yeah, I'm not native speaker in English and I misunderstood the word - to me it looked like "speeding" :) quite amusing by the way

Comment: mosquito is not correct answer..

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Leech

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> Found on all other continents

I have a similarity with moon.

> Must be something to do with their life cycle

I prefer night than day.

> They are nocturnal

I like only liquids.

> Most are sanguivorous

I am very strong in fasting.

> Can go up to 1 year without feeding

I have useless eyes.

> They are nocturnal

Comment: Leeches aren't nocturnal, though...I have only ever had them attach during the day.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> a bear

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> Polar bears are only in the Arctic

I have a similarity with the moon.

> Sun bears?

I prefer night to day.

> Bears can be nocturnal

I like only liquids.

> Bears often fish in streams

I am very strong in fasting.

> Bears hibernate over winter.

I have useless eyes.

> Bears are commonly thought to have poor eyesight.

Comment: You need to narrow down your answer to a specific species that lives on the opposite side of the globe, then the similarity to the moon will be evident (the color).

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess and say:

> Cactus

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> There are no cacti in Antarctica.

I have a similarity with the moon.

> Cacti live in a dry environment and the moon is dry.

I prefer night to day.

> There is a [species of cactus that blooms at night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night-blooming_cereus).

I like only liquids.

> Even though cacti need water to live...

I am very strong in fasting.

> ...they can go a long time without it.

I have useless eyes.

> The "i" of cacti.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> bed bugs

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> No habitat in Antarctica.

I have a similarity with moon.

> A moon feeds(depends) on sun's light and bug feeds on blood.

I prefer night than day.

> They are nocturnal.

I like only liquids.

> Blood

I am very strong in fasting.

> can live without food for many days.

I have useless eyes.

> they have compound eyes

Answer (score 2):

You're a

> Lighthouse

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> No solid ground in Antarctica

I have a similarity with the moon.

> You light the night!

I prefer night to day.

> Lighthouses fill no purpose daytime

I like only liquids.

> Lighthouses are a seafarers friend, uncommon on solid ground.

I am very strong in fasting.

> Hardest one... Guess a lot of lighthouses are in remote places and supplied to last...

I have useless eyes.

> A lighthouse is seen, not seeing.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please take the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), that will earn you a badge.

Comment: Doesn't fit the "strong in fasting" line very well ...

Comment: No solid ground in Antarctica? That entire continent and its mountain ranges would like to disagree...

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A snake?

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> Found on all other continents

I have a similarity with moon.

> A curled up snake can look like a crescent moon OR (bringing this up just to fit in) - in Hinduism, both moon and a cobra are related to Lord Shiva

I prefer night than day.

> Snakes are cold-blooded but not necessarily nocturnal; guessing they like to hunt during night

I like only liquids.

> Okay this is totally out-of-sync with the answer. I can't think of why a snake would like only liquids

I am very strong in fasting.

> Can go longer time without eating

I have useless eyes.

> They use Jacobson's organ for navigation and to detect movements

Answer (score 1):

Are you…

> A spider

I have no cousins in Antarctica.

> There are no spiders on Antarctica. (Except possibly some sea-spiders?)

I have a similarity with the moon.

> ? There is a species called "crescent comb-foot spider", latin name "achaearanea lunata", could fit.

I prefer night to day.

> Many spiders are nocturnal.

I like only liquids.

> There is a common myth that spiders only suck the juices out of their prey, not eating the solids.

I am very strong in fasting.

> Spiders can go for extended periods without food.

I have useless eyes.

> Only the main eyes of spiders actually form images, and some species have outright false eyes.